# Spring MVC3 Rest Call Getting http406 using angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, html, spring-mvc

Here is my environment

- Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE
- included jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.9.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.7.9.jar
- Tomcat 6.x
- mvc:annotation-driven in Spring configuration XML file

Comment: angular code is:function fetchResponse() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
  var REST_SERVICE_URI1='http://localhost:8080/mnp-bundle/mnp/createSubscriberResponse.htm';
        $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI1)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }

Comment: Controller Code:   //-------------------Retrieve Created Subscriber Response--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/createSubscriberResponse.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<AddModel> getResponse() {
 
 AddModel model=responseList.get(0);
  return new ResponseEntity<AddModel>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the mapping extension in the requestmapping of the method.

As of spring 3.2.x onwards the extension of the mapping has prevalence over the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers at the time of resolving the expected content types. So, as you have defined the mapping as `.htm`, content negotiation resolver expects it to return `html` and nothing else. More info [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)

So use a non extension mapping or a generic one (I usually define my rest mappings with `.service` extension).

Be aware or reviewing the spring's dispatcher servlet mapping in web.xml o configuration class, as you might need to change or add additional mappings in order to make new mapping reach your controller.

Comment: Problem is resolved i removed .htm from url and now its working perfectly.

Comment: You could better mark my answer as accepted or provide a answer by your own in order to appear your question as resolved for listings and filtering