# 406 (Not Acceptable) , getting response from controller but angular unable to catch it

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to display data in a table, I am getting list in controller but the angularjs is not accepting the response from controller. I am using spring 4.3.10 version, hibernate 5.2.2 final and angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js. I am not getting how to solve this problem.

> lib:

```
jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar  
jackson-core-2.6.5.jar  
jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar  
Spring 4.3.10  
hibernate 5.2.2 final
```

> Dispatcher-servlet:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.scm" />
 <context:annotation-config />

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 

<bean   
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.
annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" 

class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

> Controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused", "rawtypes" })
@RequestMapping(value="/DMRequestToVCMD1",method=RequestMethod.GET, 
headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map getCommodityCodes(Model model,HttpServletRequest 
request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    Map m = new HashMap();
    String uname = (String) session.getAttribute("user_name");
    String district_code = (String) session.getAttribute("district_code");
    List<AllotmentBean> list = null;
    String exception = null;
    try
    {
        list = scm_service.getAllotmentCommodities(uname);
        System.out.println("list=============="+list.size());
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        exception = ex.getMessage();
    }

    m.put("list", list);
    m.put("exception", exception);
    return m;   
 }
```

> Get method:

```
$scope.getCommoditycode = function () {
    $http.get('http://'+addres+'/Template/DMRequestToVCMD1.html')
    .then(
            function(response){
                console.error(" error response.data.list======");
                console.error(" error 
response.data.list==========="+response.data.list);
                 $scope.countries = response.data.list;

            }, 
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while getting offices');

            }
    );

 return true;
 };
```

Comment: Can you try the request from javascript without the .html prefix in the path?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993242/4190848